# CSS doesn't work when using DOCTYPE

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I have a very simple html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/assets/css/main.css" />
</head>
<body>
        <div>hello world!</div>
        <br/>
        <div id='global_footer'>copyright 2013</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The main.css is:

```
body { font-family: arial; background-color: rgb(185,179,175); }
```

I make sure the link works fine by clicking the link from browser's source code page and the browser does load the css source code correctly.

However, the CSS doesn't apply to the page. If I remove the DOCTYPE line, exactly the same code works fine. Really have no idea what's the reason.

For more information, I am using CodeIgniter. assets folder is under my document root, sibling with application folder. I have added css to the root's .htaccess to make sure it loads the css file correctly without adding index.php. I think the CI related setting is fine and the browser can locate the css file, otherwise it shouldn't work without the DOCTYPE line.

Thank you.

----EDIT----

Guys, thank you for testing out the html and css. I tested and they work fine themselves. I think the problem is from CI. I have assets folder in my document root, inside a subfoder and the main.css file. Have no idea why this html and css doesn't work under CI. My controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -  
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in 
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index()
{
    $this->load->helper(array('html','url'));
    $this->load->view('main');
}
}

/* End of file welcome.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/welcome.php */
```

Thank you.

Comment: it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/eHDS3/ (view source on the preview and you'll see it has `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Works perfectly for me, I even tested it locally without JSFiddle.

Comment: do you load your html file from http://127.0.0.1/... or from HD

Comment: BTW: you don't need `http://127.0.0.1` in link to css. `http://127.0.0.1` works only on local server on your computer but it will not work on remote server.

Comment: http://127.0.0.1/ and localhost both link to local server but you should not mix those two, use one or the other

Comment: @furas thank you. I just use <?php base_url(); ?>assets/css/main.css in the link. I think it will work fine when I move from local server to production. As GCyrillus said, both should work fine.

Comment: @GCyrillus I load my page from http://127.0.0.1. The controller is the default in router configure and I modified .htaccess to trim index.php . So all I type in browser address bar is 127.0.0.1. The page loads up correctly but no style is applied. By removing DOCTYPE, everything works fine...

Comment: sorry, i don't get it, it should workl.I'll be curious.

Comment: @Steve use relative path `href="/assets/css/main.css"`. It will work on all servers. Use relative path for css files, javascript files and images.

Comment: Well, first time to find Stackoverflow not very inclusive. I didn't intend to ask a vague question like this. I wish I could know a narrower direction what could cause the problem. It is a problem to me mostly because I didn't know what could go wrong. Anyway. Thank you for all the suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

thank you for all the information/help. I just found the issue:

CSS external files work only under the correct MIME type. My previous MIME type is text/plain. I didn't configure anything in my .htaccess and it somehow is set to this in my CI. To fix this, I need to change the MIME type to text/css. Using Apache, I add

```
AddType text/css .css
```

to my .htaccess. Now it works.

This question can be closed now. Thank you all for the help.

Comment: Just tick the mark to close the question.